# How can I integrate my rest based java webapp with okta for sso?

Tags: java, jersey, okta

I have a webapp that provides rest based end points built using jersey. I have a frontend in Angular material that consumes these stateless rest endpoints. Now I have a requirement for authentication in which I need to integrate the app with okta for SSO in particular moderation pages. Any idea on how I can proceed as I only have stateless services with me and I do not want to store authentication info with angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this sounds like you have something similar to a single page web app (meaning an app running in the browser) that calls a backend REST API.

If that's your situation, I would suggest you to go with OpenID Connect and the Implicit Flow. You can find code samples at https://github.com/jpf/okta-oidc-beta (which will leverage the Okta Sign In Widget) and at https://github.com/mcguinness/okta-oidc-sample (which is using the Okta Authentication JavaScript SDK).

The Okta Sign In Widget is an order of magnitude easier to use so I would recommend you to go that route first (+ it provides full support for password resets, multi factor authentication, etc...).

You will also find some good information and resources on our OpenID Connect page for developers, which you will find at http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/oidc.html.

Comment: Thanks Raphael. It's exactly what I've been looking for.